# How to connect mysql in 000webhost?

Tags: c#, mysql

I create a free host in 000webhost. It is active, here is link http://rndsctvlab.hostei.com/.

[image: info]

Then I create database have information

```
 $mysql_host = "mysql10.000webhost.com";
 $mysql_database = "a9127803_data1";
 $mysql_user = "<username>";
 $mysql_password = "<password>";
```

Now I want to connect and add data to mysql on this host from my pc. I write a code in C# but it fail,

It warning

[image]

Here is my code

```
string myConnection = "Server=31.170.160.97;Database=a9127803_data1;   Port=3306;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>";
        conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        string Query = "INSERT into ex1 (ID,Name,Address) values ('" + txt_ID.Text + "','" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "');";
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDatabase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("SAVE");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

How can I fix it? Thank you for help.

Comment: I removed your login credentials for security reasons. I would suggest to also remove hostnames, ports, software versions etc as they are not exactly relevant to the problem, but they present you with new (unintended) security issues. You're now basically saying: "Hey guys, here's my database which listens on this port and is version X. On this server, there's a table that has these columns with (personal?) information". You never know who reads your question and decides to take a look (or worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before and found that I needed to allow user permissions from IP addresses on MySQL 5 databases.

So for example, if you use MySQL Workbench or MySQL Query Broswer, the query would be like this to allow all hosts:

`GRANT ALL ON a9127803_data1.* TO 'a9127803_data2'@'YourIpAddress';`

Not quite sure how 000webhost works, or if you can do queries from there, but the above MySQL query is what helped me. You can customise it for each database and user.

EDIT:
Should you need to customise the permissions, look at this [MySQL link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) for more examples using the `GRANT` syntax

EDIT 2:
If you need to grant permissions via command line, here is an example:

```
cd C:\mysql //push to your MySQL directory on your server
.\bin\mysql -u user -p
//Enter Password now

grant all on YourDb.YourDbTable to YourUser@YourIpAddress;
```

Once you enter this, it should grant the permissions for your user on the IP address of your choosing, for the database and table selected.

Comment: But this host is on unknown server. I can config it like that :(

Comment: Can you do queries natively on your database? Or do you have to do them from you C# code?

Comment: I write code to connect local host (wamp server), it works. I think I replace "replace" localhost by "IP server" it will work. But It fail

Comment: All your code looks okay, connection string is fine, but I'm thinking the database itself needs configuring to allow your PC to connect. Apparently the answer before mine has done this, but looks like it is still not working for you. 

Is there any way you can write queries on the server itself?

Comment: I understand your idea, but as I known, using this  syntax GRANT ALL ON a9127803_data1.* TO 'a9127803_data2'@'YourIpAddress'; I need to use command line and  config on host server (000webhost). How can I config it? Sorry, if I wrong :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90309/discussion-between-nistelrooy41001662-and-seans).